# Derivatives at a discontinuity

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, discontinuity

The function $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ has a point discontinuity at $x=0$ but the function `Sinc[x]` takes account of the fact that the squeeze theorem suggests the sensible result `Sinc[x]==0`. However, if I attempt to evaluate the derivative at `Sinc[0]` using either `Sinc'[0]` or `D[Sinc[x],x] /. x->0`, Mathematica returns an error.

I have a large number of functions that involve `Sinc[x]` in some way, and it would be convenient if I could ensure that both the first and second derivatives of `Sinc[x]` at `x=0` were evaluated correctly. Is there a standard approach to dealing with this kind of problem in Mathematica? If so, how?

Comment: The sinc function has the Taylor series of sin divided by x. Its an even  entire analytic function looking like the complex cos near z=0, going to zero on the real line at infinity, while growing like cosh in imaginary direction. Essential singularity at complex infinity.

Comment: Try `Limit[D[Sinc[x], x], x -> 0]`  or `Limit[D[Sin[x]/x, x], x -> 0]`?

Comment: I don't have a problem finding, or knowing, what the value of `Sinc'[0]` is. I understand exactly what it is, and indeed, I would use the limit approach / squeeze theorem, as I commented, in order to evaluated any of the derivatives. My problem is only to have Mathematica evaluate it correctly in a complicated formula so I'm not manually intervening every time that `Sinc'[0]` pops up.

Comment: For those who posted the close/duplicate response, thank you. I had looked for "discontinuity" but had not specifically looked for a solution to the `Sinc'[0]` problem, thinking that it would be too specific. The duplicate (earlier) answer is very helpful.